# setsize doesn't resize immediately

Tags: java

I'm working with a simple checkerboard program, and it works fine, but it is very tiny. I tried using the acm.graphics.setsize method to resize the window, but it doesn't resize until after I place my graphics objects. Do I need to do something to "flush" the changes to the program so it works properly?

Thanks

```
/* File CheckerBoard.java
 * ----------------------
 * This program creates a checkerboard
 */

import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;

/* This class draws a checkerboard on the graphics window. 
 * The size of the checkerboard is determined by the
 * constants NROWS and NCOLUMNS, and the checkerboard fills
 * the verticle space available.
 */

public class CheckerBoard extends GraphicsProgram 
{
        /* Number of rows */
    private static final int NROWS = 8;

    /* Number of columns */
    private static final int NCOLUMNS = 8;

    // Window Size
    private static final int height = 1024;
    private static final int width = 1024;


    /* Runs the program */
    public void run() 
    {
        setSize(height,width);

        int sqSize = getHeight() / NROWS;
        for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < NCOLUMNS; j++) 
            {
                int x = j * sqSize;
                int y = i * sqSize;
                GRect sq = new GRect (x, y, sqSize, sqSize);
                sq.setFilled(((i + j) % 2) != 0);
                add (sq);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed somebody gve this question a -1 for some reason. Just so everybody knows, I have been searching online, especially in the acm documentation for an answer to this seemingly basic question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `validate()` to apply the `setSize()`. Otherwise `validate()` won't be called until after it is too late. `validate()` is used to "validate" certain operations in graphical user interface classes, generally when it relates to resizing or restyling post-initialization.

```
    setSize(height,width);
    validate();
```

However, you *should probably* use the `init()` method you have at your disposal to set up the applet, and if you do that, you do not need to call `validate()` manually, example:

```
public void init() {
    setSize(height,width);
}

/* Runs the program */
public void run() 
{
    int sqSize = getHeight() / NROWS;
    for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < NCOLUMNS; j++) 
        {
            int x = j * sqSize;
            int y = i * sqSize;
            GRect sq = new GRect (x, y, sqSize, sqSize);
            sq.setFilled(((i + j) % 2) != 0);
            add (sq);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y.O.U. F.R.E.A.K.I.N. R.O.C.K. Many days I have searched for this simple answer? I will use the init method you showed above, since I suspect I will be getting into the init method at some point, but both worked exactly as advertised. Thanks!!

Comment: @cassius Just a tip, but if my answer fixed your issue it would be a nice thing to accept it.

Comment: I thought I did. Sorry - I clicked the up arrow but not the check mark.  Thanks again!